# Identifying SSH version for OpenVMS 5.5

Tags: ssh, versioning, openvms

Is there an easy way to identify the version of SSH that ships with OpenVMS version 5.5?

The banner reveals

```
SSH-2.0-3.2.0
```

Which appears to be a range.

I have been unable to find a changelog, release notes or updates that would reveal the shipping versions.

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: FYI: last time I used SSH on a VMS box it has `ssh.com` version of SSH, and not OpenSSH, which is used almost everywhere else.

Comment: @Zoredache Indeed, it seems to be a customized version of the ssh.com ssh though according to HP, so I didn't want to just assume a version

Answer (score 0):

I believe that means it's SSH protocol v2.0 implementation v3.2.0.